# animación sobre texto con pseudoclase hover no funciona

Tags: html, css

Hola es mi primera pregunta. Estoy aprendiendo algo de desarrollo web, trato de hacer un formulario implementando algunos conceptos de flex-box, entonces deseo realizar una pequeña animación en los botones, que al acercar el ratón a los botones llamados ‘Register’ y ‘sign up’,  las letras se muevan un poco hacia la derecha sin deformar el tamaño de la caja que forma el botón, intente usando “transform: translateX(1rem);” en la etiqueta span:hover pero no realiza algún tipo de cambio. Cualquier tipo de sugerencia es bien recibida.

```css
body{
    background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 4rem auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 24rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
}

h2{ 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #414141;
    padding: 1rem;
}

form{   
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1rem;
}

form input{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid #858585;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

form input:hover::placeholder{
    color: orangered;
    transform: translateY(-1rem);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

form input:hover{
    border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid orangered;
}

a{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #858585;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.buttons{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

button{
    height: 3.2rem; 
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    /*transform: scale(0.95);*/
}

.register{
    background-color: #673ab7;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}

.signup{
    background-color:#ff5722;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}

span:hover{
    /*aca y otros selectores he estado usando transform: translateX(10px); sin mucho exito*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Haciendo un formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="making-form.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="email" class="email">
            <input type="text" placeholder="password" class="pwd">
        </form>
        <a href="#">forgot your password?</a>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="register"><span>register</span></button>
            <button class="signup"><span>sign up</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**texto en negrita**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La etiqueta `span` es una etiqueta en línea, es decir, por defecto tiene la propiedad `display: inline` y la propiedad transform no aplica a elementos en línea.

La solución que puedes aplicar es cambiar la propiedad `display` del `span` a `inline-block` o `block`.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span:hover {
  transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

```html
<button><span>Register</span></button>
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias

Comment: @SebastianRodriguezPenagos si te sirvió acéptala como respuesta. gracias

Comment: que pena es que no sabia como hacer eso, soy nuevo en stack overflow, y muchas gracias de nuevo